# How to install APK stored in internal memory without SD Card

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I've been trying to find out how to install stored APK from internal memory, but I continually get errors.

I've tried `getFilesDir()` but it returns

```
08-14 03:18:09.127 10089-10089/? W/zipro: Error opening archive /data/user/0/package_name/files/app-release.apk: I/O Error

08-14 03:18:09.127 10089-10089/? D/asset: failed to open Zip archive '/data/user/0/package_name/files/app-release.apk'

08-14 03:18:09.127 10089-10089/? W/PackageInstaller: Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation
```

I've also tried `Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory()` but I get a similar result.

I am attempting to install on a non-rooted device, but I have signature level app permission.

**How do I install app on a non-rooted device?**

Even

```
public void installAPKManual(String filename) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filename));
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

doesn't work. Parse error.

**Update**

It works after I use

```
file.setReadable(true, false)
```

to get world readable permission, but I wonder if there is a better way?

Comment: Have you tried?  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to retrieve the file from Environment then you need storage permission.

or if you are trying to get the file from your private storage `getCacheDir()` or `getFileDir()` you don't need permission but you must use [File Provider](https://drivy.engineering/android-fileprovider/).

if these are not the case try to install the APK manually first and see that everything is ok with the APK or not!!!

Comment: i have all the permissions... read, write, etc. I think it's just linux permissions.

Comment: did you try to install the APK manually?
is everything alright with APK